# The generous lazy caterer

Tags: optimization, circles, area, combinatorial-geometry

It is well-known that $n$ chords divide any convex shape into at most $\frac{n^2+n+2}2=T_n+1$ regions – the [lazy caterer's sequence](https://oeis.org/A000124). For example, the pancake below is cut into seven pieces by three cuts:

[image: Wozzy wins!]

If these are meant for seven people, however, someone has to take the very small central triangle, which is sad. Now suppose the lazy caterer is feeling **generous** and wants to maximise the smallest amount of food each person can get, which leads to my question.

> If a unit circle is divided into $T_n+1$ non-empty regions by $n$ chords, what is the *largest* possible area of the region with *smallest* area?

My best results for one to six cuts are shown below, with the shaded regions in each circle having the same smallest area $A$.

[image]

As discussed in [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/836122/357390), the ideal of every region having area $\frac\pi{T_n+1}$ can be attained for one and two cuts. For further cut numbers, this is not possible and I found the values of interest by [a melange of symmetry assumptions, mpmath and SciPy](https://gist.github.com/Parclytaxel/7ee3b5775386cb9ca5fb75c7e12bcef7).

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&A&\frac{A(T_n+1)}\pi\\
1&\frac\pi2=1.57079632\dots&1\\
2&\frac\pi4=0.78539816\dots&1\\
3&0.20025783\dots&0.4462\\
4&0.05900936\dots&0.2066\\
5&0.05394118\dots&0.2747\\
6&0.02456012\dots&0.1720
\end{array}$$
The last column in the above table gives $A$ as a proportion of the ideal region-wide smallest area.

I have numerically verified the optimality of the three-cut arrangement by optimising over possible arrangements (see lazy2.py in the Gist link above). The four- to six-cut arrangements have not been so verified; I am pretty sure the five-cut arrangement is also optimal and not sure about the six-cut arrangement. I am almost certain that the *four*-cut arrangement can be improved – looking at how the five-cut arrangement achieves a higher proportion of the ideal area against the trend of decreasing efficiency – but haven't had the time to do so. **What are the optimal arrangements for four to six cuts, and for seven or more cuts?**

Comment: Quite loosely related: [Pizza theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem).

Comment: You mean that the least area is determined?

Comment: and you wanna find the largest subject to that?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz No; what I mean is to find the largest possible least area.

Comment: It would be helpful if the code is written with comments and more readable variable names.

Comment: "For further cut numbers, this is not possible".  Is there a simple proof of that?  If so, please [answer my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981725/dividing-a-disc-into-equal-parts).  Please note: *simple* proof, not interested in long boring trigonometry.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel do you still happen to have the code? The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What happens if instead you wanted to minimise the largest piece?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just few (new)(?) values/shapes; free for further improvement.

Symmetric shapes only were considered.

Cutting lines are written in normal form:
$$x\cos \varphi + y\sin \varphi - r = 0.$$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & A & \frac{A(T_n+1)}{\pi} & lines \\
\hline
4 & 0.06807114... & 0.2383 & 
{  \varphi = \pm 0.4514698, r = 0.0688937; 
\\ \varphi = \pm 1.0207965, r = 0.3450090} \\
\hline
7 & 0.01685409... & 0.1555 & 
{  \varphi = \pm 1.2920277, r = 0.2081783;
\\ \varphi = \pm 2.3794749, r = 0.1845881;
\\ \varphi = \pm 2.5799602, r = 0.0680407;
\\ \varphi = \pi, r = 0.4250664 
} \\
\hline
8 & 0.01144959... & 0.1348 & 
{  \varphi = \pm 0.7247806, r = 0.1946717;
\\ \varphi = \pm 0.9329640, r = 0.0573711;
\\ \varphi = \pm 1.1974689, r = 0.2406817;
\\ \varphi = \pm 2.9276052, r = 0.2045243
} \\
\hline
9 & 0.01068619... & 0.1564 & 
{  \varphi = \pm 0.8084867, r = 0.2272170;
\\ \varphi = \pm 1.2859084, r = 0.2272170;
\\ \varphi = \pm 2.9028818, r = 0.2272170;
\\ \varphi = \pm \pi/3, r = 0.0627546;
\\ \varphi = \pi, r = 0.0627546
} \\
\hline
\end{array}

Images:

[image: 4 lines] $\qquad$
[image: 7 lines]

[image: 8 lines] $\qquad$
[image: 9 lines]